# How to create installer for .net core (single exe) application using visual studio setup project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, setup-project

I'm using visual studio 2019. I have .net core 3.1 application and i want to create msi installer for my application. I wanted to use setup project as always. I created setup project and i selected my project output as **PublishItemsOutpuGroup** Then i selected my publish profile from **PublishProfilePath** and msi created successfully but

**My Problem**

Even if i selected **single exe** in my project's publish profile when i insall created msi (created via setup project) it's not single exe. it includes all .net core dependencies. i want msi to install it as single exe file.

**What i want**

i want to use visual studio setup project and create msi file and when this msi file is installed it should create single exe without all .net core dependencies.

**Extra info:** if i go to my project and do publish, because i selected single exe in my publish profile settings it publishes single exe file as expected.

Comment: i found here that says i should select published items but in my visual studio publish items option is missing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2019